# How to find the image of a linear map?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Lets say that $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2`$ is a linear map with

$$ f(1,1)=(2,3) \\ f(0,1)=(1,-1) $$

How can we find $\text{Im}(f)$ ? What are the steps that we must follow?

Comment: Thank you talbi for your corrections. I don't know how to format it like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to expose you a general method to do the exercise.

The problem gives you two vectors $u,v \in \mathbb{R^2}$ and their images $f(u)$ and $f(v)$.
You know that we can take the canonical basis $\mathcal C=\{(1,0),(0,1)\}=\{e_1,e_2\}$ to write vectors in $\mathbb R^2$.
Note that $u=(1,1)=e_1+e_2$ and $v=(0,1)=e_2$ and since the map $f$ is linear we can see that $f(u)=f(e_1+e_2)=f(e_1)+f(e_2)=(2,3)$ and $f(v)=f(e_2)=(1,-1)\implies f(e_1)=(2,3)-(1,-1)=(1,4)$.

We can now write the representative matrix of the map $f$ respect to the canonical basis:

$$\mathcal M_{\mathcal C}^{\mathcal C}(f)=\begin{pmatrix}
1&&1\\
4&&-1
\end{pmatrix}$$
The vectors $(1,4)$ and $(1,-1)$ are linearly independent so we can conclude that $\text{dim}(f)=2$ and $Im(f)=\langle f(e_1),f(e_2)\rangle=\langle (1,4),(1,-1)\rangle$.

Comment: Thank you very much @Vajra for your time to explain to me the problem. Allow me to just write you back what I have understood.

Comment: @GeorgeMoraitis for sure! I'm glad this helped you.

Comment: Thank you.1. We must find the image of the domain. Correct? 2. =(1,1)=1+2 and  =2 Why is only =2 and not like the =(1,1)=1+2?

Comment: Look at the vector $v=(0,1)$, if you want to write as a linear combination of the vectors $e_1=(1,0)$ , $e_2=(0,1)$ it will simply be $v=1*e_2$, while the vector $(1,1)=(1,0)+(0,1)=e_1+e_2$. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I can understand it now. You just saved me. Thank you!!